# Parsing JSON String to Date Object in JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to convert a JSON string value of a DateTime from my database to a Date object in my javascript. I Keep getting an error message saying that it is an invalid date.

Data = "[{"Id":1,"EventTime":"/Date(1398981600000)/"}]"

Here is my code:

Controller:

```
public string GetEvents()
{
    var events = (from eventT in _db.Events select eventT).ToList();
    var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var json = serializer.Serialize(events);
    return json;
}
```

View:

```
var Events = [];
function GetEvents() {
    $.ajax(
    {
        type: "Get",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetEvents", "Game")",
        data: {},
        success: function (data) {
            json = data;
            var obj = JSON.parse(json);
            for (var i in obj) {
                var date = obj[i].EventTime;
                var d = date.getDate();
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var y = date.getFullYear();
                var h = date.getHours();
                var m = date.getMinutes();
                Events.push(
                    {
                    title: 'B-Day',
                    start: new Date(d,m,y,h,m),
                    end: new Date(d, m, y, h + 1, m),
                    allDay: false
                });
            }

        }
    });
}
```

Here is my error:

[image]

Comment: Can you tell us the contents of `data`?

Comment: data = "[{"Id":1,"EventTime":"\/Date(1398981600000)\/"}]"

Answer (score 0):

I added this line to parse the JSON date.

```
new Date(parseInt(date.substr(6)));
```